# Can I filter out rows in a flextable after creating the flextable in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I have a table output to a word doc in rmarkdown using FlexTable.  I import the data for the table (which is a bunch of character strings) from a seperate excel file that I use for keeping a record. I need to be able to have parts of the table reprinted throughout different parts of the final report.  Is there a way to filter out rows once the table is created so I can easily save all of the formatting? Or is that something I would have to do to the imported data and THEN create a flextable? Hope that all makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that you cannot.

This has been stated by the developer of the package, as you can see in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/95.